# What makes the difference in replace() usage?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a column in a pandas dataframe with string values which I'd like to convert to float. Example string values: '0,40', '0,50' and so on.
So first thing I try to do is replacing commas with dots.

When I try doing this

```
df.columnname = df.columnnname.replace(',', '.')
```

it doesnt' work.
What's interesting, replacing works for full values, like this:

```
df.columnname = df.columnnname.replace('0,40', '.')
```

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Side remark: if the dataframe is read using the `read_csv` function, the `decimal` argument can be used to parse decimals using `,` as the decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `regex=True` for replace substrings, if omit it pandas try replace values separate `,` and because not exist, values are not replaced:

```
df.columnname = df.columnnname.replace(',', '.', regex=True)
```

Check difference - in `new2` column is replaced only second `,`, because not substrings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnnname':['0,40',',','10']})

df['new1'] = df.columnnname.replace(',', '.', regex=True)
df['new2'] = df.columnnname.replace(',', '.')
print (df)
  columnnname  new1  new2
0        0,40  0.40  0,40
1           ,     .     .
2          10    10    10
```

Comment: I have found out that adding `str.`, before a string method also works:                 
`df.columnname = df.columnnname.str.replace(',', '.')`